# jqueryMobile: Slide reverse direction on back button

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

Working on a mobile app, I have a menu that "slides" from left to right, using:

```
 $.mobile.changePage(href, { transition: "slide", reverse: true });
```

On the page I am sliding to, I have a jqm back button, that goes back to my previous page.

The back button, "slides" the page from left to right. I want it to slide from right to left, reversing my left -> right initial transition.

I have tried:

```
<a href="index.html" data-icon="back" data-rel="back" title="Go back" data-direction="reverse" data-transition="slide">Back</a>
```

This does not work. I then thought, lets not "reverse" the transition, as it was already reversed to start with. So I tried just specifying `slide` thinking it would default to the normal slide of right -> left.

```
<a href="index.html" data-icon="back" data-rel="back" title="Go back" data-transition="slide">Back</a>
```

This also does not work. My animation on the back button keeps sliding left -> right.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using this.

Overriding the backbutton click event.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).on('touchstart', '[data-rel=back]', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.mobile.changePage("index.html", { transition: "slide", reverse: false, changeHash: false });

        });
```

I had to use `changeHash: false`, as my navigation flow did not register the page to be removed from the history when you now use the UI backbutton. This left me with cycling through all the "menu" page cycles I opened when clicking the hardware backbutton, until all is gone and the app closes.

With the `changeHash`, I now have one extra click when closing the app, which I can live with.